# Vue Call another component file method

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-chartjs

I got the file 'PieChart.vue'. On the other hand, I have another file call dashboard.vue but I cannot call PieChart.vue -> "genChart" function. Is it possible to call the function? I wanna refresh the charts. It is because Im using vuetify tabs, but vue chart js seems cannot render the chart in vuetify tab. It needs to re-render to show the charts. Any solution for this case?

PieChart.vue:

```
<script>
import { Pie } from "vue-chartjs";

export default {
    extends: Pie,
    name: "v-PieChart",
    props: {
        data: Array,
        label: Array,
        color: Array,
    },
    watch: {
        data: function (newData, oldData) {
            this.debouncedGenChart();
        },
    },
    created: function () {
        this.debouncedGenChart = _.debounce(this.genChart, 500);
    },
    methods: {
        genChart: function () {
            this.renderChart(
                {
                    labels: this.label,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            backgroundColor: this.color,
                            data: this.data,
                        },
                    ],
                },
                { responsive: true, maintainAspectRatio: false }
            );
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

Dashboard.vue:

```
<v-tabs>
    <v-tab
        :href="`#tab-AM`"
        @click="$refs.leaveChartAM.genChart()"
    >AM</v-tab>
    <v-tab
        :href="`#tab-PM`"
        @click="$refs.leaveChartPM.genChart()"
    >PM</v-tab>
    <v-tab-item :value="'tab-AM'">
        <v-PieChart
            :data="charts.leave.data"
            :label="charts.leave.label"
            :color="['#00E676', '#66BB6A', '#AED581']"
            ref="leaveChartAM"
        ></v-PieChart>
    </v-tab-item>
    <v-tab-item :value="'tab-PM'">
        <v-PieChart
            :data="charts.leave.data"
            :label="charts.leave.label"
            :color="['#00E676', '#66BB6A', '#AED581']"
            ref="leaveChartPM"
        ></v-PieChart>
    </v-tab-item>
</v-tabs>
```

Comment: Try with using props

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a custom event to call functions in between components. I have illustrated two method that you can use to bind event and call functions.

**Method 1**

---

Keep separate instance of the Vue, only to register custom event. assign it to window so that it can be accessed from eveywhere

```
// Initiate
window.Notifier = new Vue();

// Bind event
window.Notifier.$on('regenPieChartMethod1', function(message){
    //code block
});

// Call event from any component
window.Notifier.$emit('regenPieChartMethod1', message);
```

**Method 2**

---

Bind event to the parent component, so that it can be accessed from child components

```
// Bind event
this.$parent.$on('regenPieChartMethod2', function(message){
    //code block
});

// Call event from child component
this.$parent.$emit('regenPieChartMethod2', message);
```

**You can use whichever option suits for your implementation**

### Full Solution

```js
// Use a seperate Vue instance only for event
window.Notifier = new Vue();

Vue.component('dashboard', {
  methods: {
  
    callRegenPieChartMethod1 () {
    
      var message = 'Pie Chart data is regenerated using method 1';
        window.Notifier.$emit('regenPieChartMethod1', message);
    },
    
    callRegenPieChartMethod2 () {
    
      var message = 'Pie Chart data is regenerated using method 2';
      this.$parent.$emit('regenPieChartMethod2', message);
    }
  },
  template: '<div><h4>Dashboard Component</h4><button @click="callRegenPieChartMethod1">Refresh Pie Chart - Method 1</button> <button @click="callRegenPieChartMethod2">Refresh Pie Chart - Method 2</button></div>',
});


Vue.component('piechart', {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'This is initial data of the pie chart!'
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    var _t = this;
    
    // use seperate Vue instance to bind event
    window.Notifier.$on('regenPieChartMethod1', function(message){
        _t.genChart(message);
    });
    
    // bind event to the parent
    this.$parent.$on('regenPieChartMethod2', function(message){
        _t.genChart(message);
    });
  },
  methods: {
    genChart (message) {
      this.message = message;
    }
  },
  template: '<div><h4>Pie Chart Component</h4> <p>Message : {{message}}</p></div>',
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <dashboard></dashboard>
  <piechart></piechart>
</div>
```